# Error on Swagger after API Platform update

Tags: php, symfony, swagger, api-platform.com

I updated API Platform from 1.2 to 2.7 on an old project.

My API work fine, but I've an error on the Swagger HTML page :

```
TypeError:
Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\OpenApi\OpenApiFactory::__construct(): Argument #2 ($checkPath) must be of type string, null given, called in /app/var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/getLexikJwtAuthentication_ApiPlatform_Openapi_FactoryService.php on line 14

  at vendor/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle/OpenApi/OpenApiFactory.php:31
  at Lexik\Bundle\JWTAuthenticationBundle\OpenApi\OpenApiFactory->__construct(object(OpenApiFactory), null, null, null)
     (var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/getLexikJwtAuthentication_ApiPlatform_Openapi_FactoryService.php:14)
  at require('/app/var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/getLexikJwtAuthentication_ApiPlatform_Openapi_FactoryService.php')
     (var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:682)
  at ContainerCRp5KBI\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->load('getLexikJwtAuthentication_ApiPlatform_Openapi_FactoryService.php')
     (var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/getApiPlatform_SwaggerUi_ActionService.php:12)
  at require('/app/var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/getApiPlatform_SwaggerUi_ActionService.php')
     (var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:682)
  at ContainerCRp5KBI\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->load('getApiPlatform_SwaggerUi_ActionService.php')
     (var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/getApiPlatform_Swagger_Action_UiService.php:11)
  at require('/app/var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/getApiPlatform_Swagger_Action_UiService.php')
     (var/cache/dev/ContainerCRp5KBI/srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer.php:682)
  at ContainerCRp5KBI\srcApp_KernelDevDebugContainer->load('getApiPlatform_Swagger_Action_UiService.php')
     (vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php:255)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->make('api_platform.swagger.action.ui', 1)
     (vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/Container.php:231)
  at Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Container->get('api_platform.swagger.action.ui')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ContainerControllerResolver.php:53)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver->instantiateController('api_platform.swagger.action.ui')
     (vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:70)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver->instantiateController('api_platform.swagger.action.ui')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:110)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver->createController('api_platform.swagger.action.ui')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ContainerControllerResolver.php:42)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ContainerControllerResolver->createController('api_platform.swagger.action.ui')
     (vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:62)
  at Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\ControllerResolver->createController('api_platform.swagger.action.ui')
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:86)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\ControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/TraceableControllerResolver.php:38)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Controller\TraceableControllerResolver->getController(object(Request))
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:152)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), 1)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:81)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), 1, true)
     (vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:201)
  at Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(object(Request))
     (public/index.php:25)
```

Why I call the entrypoint as a JSON format, everything work fine. So I don't understand where this error comes from ?

Comment: You have the answer in the snippet you've provide.

Comment: @evgenyRuban I’m not sure to understand your answer. The stack trace only show vendors’ files, so I’m not able to edit them. I tried to understand why the constructor of OpenApiFactory is badly called, but I don’t have the answer.

Comment: An answer for those who'd have the problem: downgrade to API Platform 2.6 solves the issue (it's a good way to solve it immediately, but 2.6 is not maintained anymore).

Comment: Did you try to remove the cache entirely? It may used an old cache and provide wrong parameters when instantiating the service.

Comment: @A.L Yes, I spent a lot of time cleaning every conceivable cache.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml

```
# config/packages/lexik_jwt_authentication.yaml
lexik_jwt_authentication:
    # ...
    api_platform:
        check_path: /api/login_check
        username_path: email
        password_path: security.credentials.password
```